# Why don't these footprints give the same Boolean outcome?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2015

I have these two lines of code in a property and one evaluates to TRUE and the other evaluates to FALSE and I can't think why......

```
Not Bool1 AndAlso Not Bool2 AndAlso Not Bool3

Not (Bool1 And Bool2 And Bool3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 'And' evaluates all 3 items where 'AndAlso' only evaluates the right side if the left side is true.  In the first example, you have "Not" on the left, so it stops there.  In the second example, the entire statement is evaluated, hence the difference.

Comment: ok thanks, i see what you're saying, i think i just expected to see the same result because of the parentheses